# Issue with the gears?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, gears, shifter

My cycle seems to have this problem, that whenever I change the gear it starts changing from the second sprocket.

Whenever I start from gear one it starts from the second biggest sprocket, though it goes up to the smallest sprocket (6th one) it doesn’t climb back to the first biggest sprocket ever.

What's the issue with it?

The bike is a new one (~5 months). Since I brought it and I am facing the same issue ever since.

Is it really an issue, or is everything fine?

Thank you.

Comment: @ojs I never said it “skips”, it just doesn’t go to the bigger one while climbing up

Comment: Just read the answer about adjusting derailleur.

Comment: If you bought it from a real bike shop then you should take it back for a complementary "tune up".

Comment: @user377340 true - its a subtly different description, but the approach is the same.  Your derailleur is not sitting in the right place, and needs tweaking as described in the marked duplicate.  Its not a bad thing, don't take it wrong.   In fact its good for you because there's an answer already there for you to try.

Answer (score 3):

Either your **range adjustment** is off, or your **cable tension**.  Assuming your derailleur is not bent or damaged, this is likely what's wrong.

Your **range adjustment** screw that limits how far toward the 'big' gears you can shift needs to be loosened a little, probably as little as 1/4 turn counterclockwise.

Check your derailleur: you should have two screws, one labeled 'H' and one labeled 'L'.  Try loosening 'L' about a quarter turn.

Another possible issue is the **cable tension** could be too low, possibly because the cable has slipped or stretched. Make sure the cable clamp that secures the derailleur cable to the derailleur is snugly tightened. There should be a barrel adjuster where the cable enters the derailleur, or on the shifter body on the handlebars.  You might also try turning that counterclockwise 1/4 -1/2 turn.

Finally, make sure your chain is clean and oiled, as the friction can interfere with proper shifting.

Further reference: https://www.artscyclery.com/learningcenter/shimanorearderailleurs.html

Answer (score 2):

I can infer that a new bike with 6 speeds in the rear is an inexpensive one. It's likely it was not set up correctly when it was assembled. The rear derailleur probably just needs properly adjusting.

I'd recommend taking your bike to a local bike store and have their repair shop adjust the gears - it's a short procedure and will not be expensive. You should also ask them to have a look over the bike to check for other assembly or adjustment problems. If the gears were not set up correctly then something else may be wrong, which may cause a safety issue.

If you want to tackle it yourself, rear derailleur adjustment can look daunting, but there are several good videos available with procedures to follow that make it quite easy. My favorite is Park Tool Company's YouTube channel (link below). Also check out the Art's Cyclery link in @Matt Morgan's answer.

.